# I need to be able to create a new file to a specific directory and then write to it. when running it, it keeps on running the catch, not sure why

Tags: python

I need to create a program that will use the OS library in order to validate that a directory exists before creating a file in that directory. The program will then prompt the user for the directory they would like to save the file in as well as the name of the file. The program should then prompt the user for their name, address, and phone number. The program will then write this data to a comma-separated line in a file and store the file in the directory specified by the user.
Once the data has been written the program should read the file you just wrote to the file system and display the file contents to the user for validation purposes.

please help me because any work I'm doing is not working out.

this is what I did so far:

```
import os

print ("Hi, I can save a new file with your name, address, and phone number, in a specified directory for you.")
userPath = input("Give me the path to the directory that you want to save the new file in: \n")
try:
    os.path.isdir(userPath)
    
except:
    print("Specified directory path does not exist.")
    quit()
newFile = input("What do you want to name the new file?\n")
filePath = os.path.join(userPath, newFile)
name = input("What's your name?\n")
address = input("What's your address?\n")
number = input("What's your phone number?\n")
try:    
    with open(filePath, 'w') as file_object: #create new file
        data = (name + ", " + address + ", " + number)
        file_object.write(data) #write to file
except:
    print("Error creating/writing to new file.")
    quit()
try:
    with open(filePath) as file_object:
        print("Today we created a new file, " + newFile + ", and we added the following information to the file: ")
        print(file_object.read())
except:
    print("Error reading file.")
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was almost there, you just needed to change your try loop

```py
try:
    os.path.isdir(userPath)
    
except:
    print("Specified directory path does not exist.")
    quit()
```

Into an if statement

```py
if not os.path.isdir(userPath):
    print("Specified directory path does not exist.")
    quit()
```

Because `os.path.isdir(userPath)` returns `True` or `False`. Which is not going to work with a `try` loop (try loops use error/exceptions).

---

You should also include `Exception` or the actual exception you get when using a try loop; to ensure you don't pass the wrong exceptions.

Full code:

```py
import os

print("Hi, I can save a new file with your name, address, and phone number, in a specified directory for you.")

userPath = input(
    "Give me the path to the directory that you want to save the new file in: \n")

if not os.path.isdir(userPath):
    print("Specified directory path does not exist.")
    quit()

newFile = input("What do you want to name the new file?\n")
filePath = os.path.join(userPath, newFile)
name = input("What's your name?\n")
address = input("What's your address?\n")
number = input("What's your phone number?\n")

try:
    with open(filePath, 'w') as file_object:  # create new file
        data = (name + ", " + address + ", " + number)
        file_object.write(data)  # write to file
except Exception:
    print("Error creating/writing to new file.")
    quit()
try:
    with open(filePath) as file_object:
        print("Today we created a new file, " + newFile +
              ", and we added the following information to the file: ")
        print(file_object.read())
except Exception:
    print("Error reading file.")
    quit()
```

Comment: It actually works without making these changes so I guess it is not needed. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Sarah, What issue are you having with your code exactly?

Comment: Yes, the program could work without these changes if a path entered exists, however, if the path does not exist, your program will display the message "Error creating/writing to new file.", and a user will not easily know what the problem is, but if you implement these changes, your program will return "Specified directory path does not exist." correctly, and so a user will know what the problem is. This is known as UX.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```py
try:
    os.path.isdir(userPath)
except:
    print("Specified directory path does not exist.")
    quit()
```

To this:

```py
if not os.path.isdir(userPath):
    print("Specified directory path does not exist.")
    quit()
```

Comment: sorry, I guess I wasn't so clear. I get past the directory try block. I get an error when I try creating a new file/writing to the new file - by the second try-catch block. Thanks!

Comment: The answer I gave you fixes the error in the second try/except block.

Answer (score 1):

tried out on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04) and it worked perfectly:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXpGj.png)

I think that maybe your problem is that you need to add a full path to the program, what I mean by that is that when running the program you should not add something like:

`Downloads`

It should be like:

`/home/<your-user>/Downloads`

If you are on Windows you should use somehting like:

`C:\Downloads`

It depends on your OS, I hope that was helpful .

Comment: I will add that the full path that I'm talking to is when the program prompts you the 

`Give me the path to the directory that you want to save the new file in:`

So yo add the full path there:

`Give me the path to the directory that you want to save the new file in:
/home/youngermaster/Downloads/stackOverflowStuff`

And that's it.



Comment: Thanks, I think my mistake was that I copied the path from file explorer and it came along with double-quotes, when I removed them it worked.

Comment: @Sarah I'm glad it helped you realize that, have a great night and good luck with your Cybersecurity career .

*Note:* Don't forget to add the `upvotes` and that the `question was solved` 